# How to register custom converters in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I writing application using spring-boot-starter-jdbc (v1.3.0).

The problem that I met: Instance of `BeanPropertyRowMapper` fails as it cannot convert from `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

In order to copy this problem, I implemented 
`org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` for these types.

```
public class TimeStampToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(Timestamp s) {
        return s.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I make available `TimeStampToLocalDateTimeConverter` for `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

More general question, how do I register my converters, in order to make them available system wide?

The following code bring us to `NullPointerException` on initialization stage:

```
private Set<Converter> getConverters() {
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();
    converters.add(new TimeStampToLocalDateTimeConverter());
    converters.add(new LocalDateTimeToTimestampConverter());

    return converters;
}

@Bean(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    bean.setConverters(getConverters()); 
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just add your converter as a bean... Remove everything else.

Comment: Confusing `HttpMessageConverter` and `Converter` here. Just add a class that extends `WebMVcConfigurerAdapter` and implement the `addFormatters` method. On the `FormatterRegistry` call `addConverter` for the ones you want to add.

Comment: I do not have web environment at all.

Comment: Then it indeed won't work :). But the code you have should work, can you add the full configuration class and the error you get (the stack trace) when you use this...

Comment: To save some code I wouldn't call the `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()`. instead let Spring do that for you, simply return the factory bean.

Comment: Possible duplicated off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025550/register-spring-converter-programmatically-in-spring-boot/41205653#41205653

Answer (score 4):

All custom conversion service has to be registered with the FormatterRegistry. Try creating a new configuration and register the conversion service by implementing the WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new TimeStampToLocalDateTimeConverter());
    }
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: ``` Thanks. But the method name should be addFormatters() ```

Comment: This only works in a WebMVC context. The question asker specifically asked to be able to use the convert system-wide. This does not accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll copy my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781591/140707 since I think the two questions are similar (so the answer applies to both).

---

Existing answers didn't work for me:

- Customizing via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addFormatters` (or simply annotating the converter with `@Component`) only works in the WebMvc context and I want my custom converter to be available *everywhere*, including `@Value` injections on any bean.
- Defining a `ConversionService` bean (via `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` `@Bean` or `@Component`) causes Spring Boot to replace the default `ApplicationConversionService` on the `SpringApplication` bean factory with the custom bean you've defined, which will probably be based on `DefaultConversionService` (in `AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization`). The problem is that Spring Boot adds some handy converters such as `StringToDurationConverter` to the standard set in `DefaultConversionService`, so by replacing it you lose those conversions. This may not be an issue for you if you don't use them, but it means that solution won't work for everyone.

I created the following `@Configuration` class which did the trick for me. It basically adds custom converters to the `ConversionService` instance used by `Environment` (which is then passed on to `BeanFactory`). This maintains as much backwards compatibility as possible while still adding your custom converter into the conversion services in use.

```java
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void addCustomConverters() {
        ConfigurableConversionService conversionService = environment.getConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(new MyCustomConverter());
    }
}
```

Obviously you can autowire a list of custom converters into this configuration class and loop over them to add them to the conversion service instead of the hard-coded way of doing it above, if you want the process to be more automatic.

To make sure this configuration class gets run before any beans are instantiated that might require the converter to have been added to the `ConversionService`, add it as a *primary source* in your spring application's `run()` call:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class<?>[] { MySpringBootApplication.class, ConversionServiceConfiguration.class }, args);
    }
}
```

If you don't do this, it might work, or not, depending on the order in which your classes end up in the Spring Boot JAR, which determines the order in which they are scanned. (I found this out the hard way: it worked when compiling locally with an Oracle JDK, but not on our CI server which was using a Azul Zulu JDK.)

Note that for this to work in `@WebMvcTest`s, I had to also combine this configuration class along with my Spring Boot application class into a `@ContextConfiguration`:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MySpringBootApplication.class, ConversionServiceConfiguration.class })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { /* ... properties to inject into beans, possibly using your custom converter ... */ })
class MyControllerTest {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This approach is what solved my problem, thank you @Frans! Using the `addFormatters` in the `WebMvcConfigurer` didn't work. In my case, I wanted to convert a string specified in `application.yml` to its corresponding enum when used with `@Value`, where the string I associate with the enum value is not the same as the string representation of the value (i.e. `public enum MyEnum { ONE("a-different-value") ... }`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use @Autowired and the related dependency injection mechanism of spring to use a single ConversionService instance throughout your application. The ConversionService will be instantiated within the configuration.

All Converters to be available application wide receive an annotation (e.g. @AutoRegistered). On application start a @Component FormatterRegistrar (Type name itself is a bit misleading, yes it is "...Registrar" as it does the registering. And @Component as it is fully spring managed and requires dependency injection) will receive @AutoRegistered List of all  annotated Converters.

See this thread for  [concrete implementation details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778099/register-converters-and-converterfactories-with-annotations-in-spring-3). We use this mechanism within our project and it works out like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer` or any on its implementation is one stop place for any kind of customization in spring boot project. It prvoides various methods, for your Converter requirement.

Just create a new Converter by extending `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S, T>`. Then register it with Spring by your class overriding method `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer.addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)`

Note there are Other types of Converter also which basically starts from ConditionalConverter.

Comment: This only works in a WebMVC context. The question asker specifically asked to be able to use the convert system-wide. This does not accomplish that.

Answer (score -2):

Trying adding

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
```

Its needs to be placed over the convertor class. This works for me in case of Convertor needed for Localdate for interacting to DB.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
      return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
      return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

This is now applied automatically while interacting with DB.

Comment: The question was about Spring (core) converters, not JPA converters.