# Register Spring Converter Programmatically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to register a Spring Converter in a Spring Boot project programmatically. In past Spring projects I've done it in XML like this...

```
<!-- Custom converters to allow automatic binding from Http requests parameters to objects -->
<!-- All converters are annotated w/@Component -->
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="stringToAssessmentConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do in Spring Boot's SpringBootServletInitializer

**Update:** I've made a little progress by passing the StringToAssessmentConverter as an argument to `getConversionService`, but now I'm getting a `"No default constructor found"` error for the StringToAssessmentConverter class. I'm not sure why Spring is not seeing the @Autowired constructor.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    ...

    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean getConversionService(StringToAssessmentConverter stringToAssessmentConverter) {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();

        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();

        converters.add(stringToAssessmentConverter);

        bean.setConverters(converters);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the Converter...

```
 @Component
 public class StringToAssessmentConverter implements Converter<String, Assessment> {

     private AssessmentService assessmentService;

     @Autowired
     public StringToAssessmentConverter(AssessmentService assessmentService) {
         this.assessmentService = assessmentService;
     }

     public Assessment convert(String source) {
         Long id = Long.valueOf(source);
         try {
             return assessmentService.find(id);
         } catch (SecurityException ex) {
             return null;
         }
     }
 }
```

Full Error

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-
plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project yrdstick: An exception 
occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating 
bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPo
stProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in 
me.jpolete.yrdstick.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter]: : Error 
creating bean with name 'stringToAssessmentConverter' defined in file 
[/yrdstick/target/classes/me/jpolete/yrdstick/websupport
/StringToAssessmentConverter.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
to instantiate 
[me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter]: No default 
constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter.<init>(); 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'stringToAssessmentConverter' defined in file [/yrdstick
/dev/yrdstick/target/classes/me/jpolete/yrdstick/websupport
/StringToAssessmentConverter.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
to instantiate 
[me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter]: No default 
constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter.<init>()
```

Comment: try like this converters.add(new StringToAssessmentConverter());

Comment: @Shaheer I can't instantiate it with new. StringToAssessmentConverter has it's own Autowired dependencies.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The answer is, you only need to anotate your converter as `@Component`:

This is my converter example

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
@Component
public class DateUtilToDateSQLConverter implements Converter<java.util.Date, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(java.util.Date source) {
        return new Date(source.getTime());
    }
}
```

Then when Spring needs to make convert, the converter is called.

My Spring Boot Version: `1.4.1`

Comment: thanks for mentioning this. unfortunatelly this is not documented anywhere in the spring docs.

Comment: @eav true, this is something helpful and simple to use, need to be documented

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. You're correct. All you need to do is annotate with @Component. Not sure if there was an issue with earlier versions of Spring Boot, or if I had some other problem. Marking this as correct.

Comment: @deFreitas - Could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615922/field-error-in-object-target-on-field-rejected-value-codes-typemismat ?

Comment: [Spring Boot 2.2.4 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration): "The auto-configuration adds the following features on top of Spring’s defaults:Automatic registration of Converter, GenericConverter, and Formatter beans."

Comment: Also, using `converter-annotation-processor` (https://careem.github.io/converter-codegen/) we can autogenerate the converters!

Comment: I seem to have lost this auto-configuration when creating my own `WebMvcConfiguration` (replacing `@EnableMvc`). Might be useful for others to know that stumble apon this question.

Comment: If the converter is needed to convert properties to specific objects registering it as component might be too late. I'm using In spring-boot-2.3.11 and get an error `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.raisercostin.jedio.WritableDirLocation]`

Answer (score 5):

**If you are not on Spring Boot, where automatic registration of converters annotated with @Component (and similar stereotype annotations) is performed and you are **not in Web Mvc environment** :

```
@Bean
ConversionService conversionService(){
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter<?, ?>> convSet = new HashSet<Converter<?, ?>>();
    convSet.add(new MyConverter()); // or reference bean convSet.add(myConverter());
    factory.setConverters(convSet);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

A TypeConverter Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface TypeConverter {
}
```

A Converter Registrar:

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    @TypeConverter
    private Set<Converter<?, ?>> autoRegisteredConverters;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    @TypeConverter
    private Set<ConverterFactory<?, ?>> autoRegisteredConverterFactories;

    @Autowired
    private ConverterRegistry converterRegistry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void conversionService() {
        if (autoRegisteredConverters != null) {
            for (Converter<?, ?> converter : autoRegisteredConverters) {
                converterRegistry.addConverter(converter);
            }
        }
        if (autoRegisteredConverterFactories != null) {
            for (ConverterFactory<?, ?> converterFactory : autoRegisteredConverterFactories) {
                converterRegistry.addConverterFactory(converterFactory);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then annotate your converters:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@TypeConverter
public class StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Enum> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnum(targetType);
    }

    private final class StringToEnum<T extends Enum> implements Converter<String, T> {

        private Class<T> enumType;

        public StringToEnum(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T convert(String source) {
            return (T) Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim().toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks elegant, however when I tried, I got an error, perhaps spring version difference?  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [void

Comment: From HibernateJpa‌​AutoConfiguration, you probably are using Spring Boot. As far as I know, Spring Boot already supports autoregistering converters out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025550/register-spring-converter-programmatically-in-spring-boot This solution was for bare Spring, not for Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public AssessmentService assessmentService(){
        return new AssessmentService();
    }

    @Bean
    public StringToAssessmentConverter stringToAssessmentConverter(){
        return new StringToAssessmentConverter(assessmentService());
    }

    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();    
        Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();

        //add the converter
        converters.add(stringToAssessmentConverter()); 

        bean.setConverters(converters);
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    // separate these class into its own java file if necessary
    // Assesment service
    class AssessmentService {}

    //converter
    class StringToAssessmentConverter implements Converter<String, Assessment> {

         private AssessmentService assessmentService;

         @Autowired
         public StringToAssessmentConverter(AssessmentService assessmentService) {
             this.assessmentService = assessmentService;
         }

         public Assessment convert(String source) {
             Long id = Long.valueOf(source);
             try {
                 return assessmentService.find(id);
             } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                 return null;
             }
         }

     }
}
```

or if your StringToAssessmentConverter is already a spring bean:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService(StringToAssessmentConverter stringToAssessmentConverter) {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();    
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();

    //add the converter
    converters.add(stringToAssessmentConverter); 

    bean.setConverters(converters);
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: Where is the stringToAssessmentConverter() method you're calling?

Comment: Never mind. I see. That will probably work, but I want to take advantage of Spring's component and autowired annotations rather than manually wiring up the objects.

Comment: See my updated answer. Basically annotating class as `@Component` is the same as annotating method with `@Bean`.

Comment: Thanks. See my update to the original question. I'm doing what you suggest. `StringToAssessmentConverter` is a Spring Bean annotated with `@Component`, but now I'm getting a `Failed to instantiate [me.jpolete.yrdstick.websupport.StringToAssessmentConverter]: No default constructor found;` I have the `StringToAssessmentConverter` constructor annotated with `@Autowired`. Not sure why that constructor isn't getting called.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot it looks like:

```
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    // do not replace with lambda as spring cannot determine source type <S> and target type <T>
    registry.addConverter(new Converter<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer convert(String text) {
            if (text == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String trimmed = StringUtils.trimWhitespace(text);
            return trimmed.equals("null") ? null : Integer.valueOf(trimmed);
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had problem with registration custom converter in xml config.
Should to add converter id to annotation-driver

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="ru.javawebinar.topjava.util.StringToLocalDateConverter"/>
            </set>
        </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
```

Reference links:
[Spring MVC. Type Conversion,](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-conversion)
[Spring Core. Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#core-convert)

Answer (score 0):

If the converter is needed to convert properties to specific objects registering it as component might be too late. I'm using spring-boot-2.3.11 and get an error `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.raisercostin.jedio.WritableDirLocation]`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'revobet.feed.lsports.rest.dump-dir' to org.raisercostin.jedio.WritableDirLocation:

    Property: myapp.dump-dir
    Value: file://localhost/C:\Users\raiser/.myapp/cache
    Origin: class path resource [myapp.conf]:-1:1
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.raisercostin.jedio.WritableDirLocation]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

## solution

```
public class MyApp implements ApplicationRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocationsConverterConfig.init();
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

and the Converter

```
public class LocationsConverterConfig {
  public static void init() {
    ApplicationConversionService conversionService = (ApplicationConversionService) ApplicationConversionService
      .getSharedInstance();
    log.info("adding JacksonStringToObjectConverter to handle Locations serialization as soon as possible");
    conversionService.addConverter(new JacksonStringToObjectConverter());
  }

  //@Component
  public static class JacksonStringToObjectConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {

    public JacksonStringToObjectConverter() {
      log.info("adding {} to handle Locations serialization as soon as possible", JacksonStringToObjectConverter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
      return Collections.singleton(new ConvertiblePair(Object.class, Object.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Object convert(@Nullable Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```