# Custom deserialization of path variable in spring web starter

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

What is the correct way to register a custom deserializer for a path variable in Spring web reactive?

Example:

```
@GetMapping("test/{customType}")
public String test(@PathVariable CustomType customType) { ...
```

I tried ObjectMapperBuilder, ObjectMapper and directly via @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTypeMapper.class) but it wont register:

```
Response status 500 with reason "Conversion not supported."; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type '...CustomType'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type '...CustomType': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Perhaps try providing a [Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) and also [register it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025550/register-spring-converter-programmatically-in-spring-boot).

Comment: @JourneyCorner are you using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using @ModelValue because it semantically is not a deserialization, just parsing a key.

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

   @GetMapping("test/{customType}")
   public String test(@ModelAttribute CustomType customType) { ... }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

   @ModelAttribute("customType")
   public CustomType getCustomType(@PathVariable String customType) {
      CustomeType result = // map value to object
      return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For path variables deserialization you don't need to involve jackson, you can use [org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#core-convert-Converter-API)

For example:

```
@Component
public class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter
  implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(
          source, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }
}

@GetMapping("/findbydate/{date}")
public GenericEntity findByDate(@PathVariable("date") LocalDateTime date) {
    return ...;
}
```

[Here's an article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) with examples