# Custom type conversion of property values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, type-conversion, properties-file

I have a `myapp.properties` file with key-value pairs defined as:

```
prefix.int-field=123
prefix.string-field=asdf
prefix.custom-type-field=my.package.CustomType
```

I am trying to inject these properties by using a `@Value` annotation in a following class:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:myapp.properties")
@Component
class MySettings {
    @Value("${prefix.int-field}")
    private int intField;

    @Value("${prefix.string-field}")
    private String stringField;

    @Value("${prefix.custom-type-field}") // <-- this is the problem
    private CustomInterface customField;
}

class CustomType implements CustomInterface {...}

interface CustomInterface {...}
```

Now, `intField` and `stringField` get initialized with the desired values as expected, but `customField` throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [my.package.CustomInterface]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

How can I convert the text property values to my custom type?

I tried to consult the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config), but I fail to see the correct way of doing it. I am using Spring Boot 1.3.6.

Comment: have you tried to add your custom Converter? It should be a class implementing Converter<String, Class>, more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239585/how-to-register-custom-converters-in-spring-boot

Comment: Why don't you just inject it like a bean?

Comment: @freakman I haven't tried that yet, I'm new to Spring and confused about things. I'll give it a shot

Comment: @grape_mao but I want `customField` to be configurable through the properties file, that is, if I later choose to use a different implementation of `CustomInterface` I can just change the properties file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your immediate issue you want to look at the [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) option on the bean. That will allow you to act on things before the bean is made available to the context.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:myapp.properties")
@Component
class MySettings {
    @Value("${prefix.int-field}")
    private int intField;

    @Value("${prefix.string-field}")
    private String stringField;

    @Value("${prefix.custom-type-field}")
    private String customFieldType;

    private CustomInterface customField;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        customField = (CustomInterface) Class.forName(customFieldType).newInstance(); // short form... will need checks that it finds the class and can create a new instance
    }
}

class CustomType implements CustomInterface {...}

interface CustomInterface {...}
```

I am curious if you might want to use the `@Configuration` annotation on a class and create an instance of the `CustomInterface` that is made available as a bean on the Spring ApplicationContext. To do that you would instead do something like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
class MySettings {
    private int intField;

    private String stringField;

    private String customTypeField;

    // getters and setters
}
```

That would then be used in an `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CustomInterface customInterface(MySettings mySettings) {
        return (CustomInterface) Class.forName(mySettings.getCustomTypeField()).newInstance();
    }
}
```

At this point you would now have an instantiated bean for `CustomInterface` that you can have Spring autowire into other objects.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. I've tried the 2 solutions you suggested and they both work nicely. (though the first one is more verbose, it offers the ability to ctrl+click (intellij idea) on the `${...}` value string which takes you straight to the property in `.properties` file. I'll accept your answer although I may not end up using it, since my custom types can have constructor parameters, so I'll probably have to approach it totally differently.

Comment: @radoh I realize this is "a bit" old question, but it'd still be nice to see you post an answer on how you eventually managed to include those constructor parameters...